# How can I place my advertisement in an android app?

Tags: android, ios, ads

when looking for an answer I only found info for app devs who want to monetarize their app, but nothing from the advertiser's perspective. So I hope you can help me:

Is it possible to place my ads in someone else's app (android or iOS)?
I'm working for a small company planning to place their ads in specific apps/games which are related to our products.

And if yes, how can this be accomplished?

Thanks alot in advance!

Regards

GC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google's AdSense is what you are looking for.

For more information this could help:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en

For more information search on Google's sites or contact them directly.

EDIT: Obviously this will only work for Android.